# Why my Route attribute is not working on this Azure Functions v2?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure Functions, put a Route atribute, it does not work.

If I put the Route parameter, then it works.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("StartUserSession")]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("Client/StartUserSession")]
    public static IActionResult StartUserSession([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, methods: new string[] { "get", "post" }
    //, Route ="Client/StartUserSession"
    )]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        var UserId = req.Query["UserId"];

        return new OkObjectResult($"StartUserSession, O UserId informado é {UserId}");
    }
```

If I use the Route Attribute, when I run, this appears:

[image: Route Attribute]

If I use Route parameter, then this:

[image: Route Parameter]

**How to make the Route attribute work?**

Comment: Have you seen any docs which claim it should work?

Comment: To add to Mikhail's comment, here are the docs on customizing endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint

Answer (score 0):

As @Mikhail has mentioned, Attribute `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("")]` doesn't work in Azure Function.

Azure Function has its own route operation which is a property included in HttpTrigger Attribute, as the parameter you use.
Or if you use c# script(.csx) to develop Azure Function, route can be defined in function.json file according to [custom-http-endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint) as @Marie suggested.

By default Azure Functions has a route prefix `/api/` on all functions just like WebApi does, which avoids collisions with ASP.NET MVC routing.